# Why does Microsoft Windows TaskScheduler log ^C into its redirected StdErr log file?

Tags: c, logging, windows-server-2012, stderr, windows-task-scheduler

Is it logging that it stops the application?

I am using Windows Server 2012. It's running tens of scheduled tasks for in-house applications. Their stdout and stderr get redirected by the Task Scheduler to individual log files per task:

1>>stdout.log 2>>stderr.log

When the application is almost finished, a summarizer reads its error log, picks out interesting lines, and send them via email.

Now our summarizer is complaining about the text ^C at the beginning of a line (because it expects a date, and ^C isn't a date).

I'll update the summarizer to allow for this event, but that doesn't get rid of the problem: the occurence of ^C at the beginning of a line. Any line. Seemingly at random.

The ^C is used to stop an application from running, if it was started from the (DOS) shell. Since my scheduled tasks all invoke batch files, there is a chance that the Task Scheduler is logging to StdErr that it force-quit a scheduled application.

However, the occurrences don't coincide with moments that the Task Scheduler history says that its applications stopped, and it hasn't force-quit any applications in 2 weeks. Yet there's a ^C logged today.

The ^C could have come from the logger I use. However, that logger has been in use for months, and we've only been seeing this since we started using Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ^C can get logged into my StdErr log due to the force-quit of my application by the Task Scheduler.

Despite my own insistence that no force-quit had happened according to the Task Scheduler history, I witnessed it happen yesterday.

There may be other reasons for its occurrence, but at least this particular behaviour is confirmed.